# Issues creating simple scatter plot

Tags: excel

[image]

I'm expecting the text to series labels and a series with 6 values. I've tried swapping rows to columns but got error "The maximum number of data series per chart 255". What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Similar to what I'd like to get out of the above table

[image]

Comment: The x-axis (first column selected) need to have numeric values for a XY plot.

Comment: Please indicate which column is the X-axis and which column(s) the Y-axis for the scatter plot.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Solved it by manually constructing the plot and ading the horizontal axis myself.